# MVC 5 Attribute Routing Error for multiple pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, angular7

I ran this error attempting to handle multiple routes:

---

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The layout page "Login" could not be found at the following path: "~/Views/Login/Login". 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The layout page "Login" could not be found at the following path: "~/Views/Login/Login".

---

Here is my route config code:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Login",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Dashboard",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

---

here is my _viewstart code

```
@{
    string CurrentName = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]);
    dynamic Layout;
    switch (CurrentName)
    {
        case "Login":
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoginPageLayout.cshtml";

            break;
        case "Dashboard":
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
            break;
        default:
            //Admin layout  
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
            break;
    }
}
```

Could I have some guidance as to where I might have taken a wrong turn?

Comment: Show your code in `LoginController`. Your Login method is leading to the login page, and it is not found. Where is your login.cshtml?

Comment: I think you have overlapped route since both `Login` and `Dashboard` have same route path definition. In which line the error has thrown and can you provide login view and its controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in view start just use Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

remove this part => routes.MapRoute( name: "Login", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );

just try to hit the index page of home (it's automatic with the route when your user try to reach your base site url )

and then filter the user with role on controller if not authentified redirect him to login.

dont try to break the framework in the early building of your site :)

Comment: I removed the code completely and retyped it after this and it worked.